# EasticSearch Query for type specific conditions?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to write a query to do the following:

For example: a CAR Index has the following mapping:

```
ford
    color
    model
acura
    color
    model
toyota
    color
    model
    toyota_type
```

I want to write a query that would search through all documents with 
color = "blue" , and toyota_type = "a" || "c" ONLY if the type = "toyota"

The tricky part is if I write a query like this, it only shows results of type TOYOTA, but doesn't match documents of other types:

```
Looking for: 
     ("color is blue" AND type is not toyota) OR 
     ("color is blue" AND type IS toyota AND toyota_type = 'a' or 'c')
In other words, search ALL documents; 
(1) IF type == toyota (toyota_type == 'a' or 'c' ) AND color == "blue"
(2) IF type != toyota  color == "blue"

{
      "bool": {
        "must": [{
          "term": {
            "color": "blue"
          }
        }, {
          "bool": {
            "should": {
              "terms": {
                "toyota_type": ["a","c"]
              }
            }
          }
        }]
      }
    }

edit: try this and also didn't work. This returns toyota_type != ('a' or 'c')

    {
        "query":{
            "bool": {
            "must": [{
              "term": {
                "color": 
              }
            }, {
              "bool": {
                "must_not": [{
                  "term": {
                    "color": "red"
                  }
                }]
              }
            }], 
            "should":{
                "terms":{
                    "toyota_type": ['a','c']
                }
            }
          }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using must in the top level bool query which is an AND query for elasticsearch. So, the query can be translated into finding all results where "color is blue" AND "toyota_type is either 'a' or 'c'". However, according to me what you need is the query for this: "color is blue" OR "toyota_type is either 'a' or 'c'". If this is the requirement you should have this query in place.

```
{
  "bool": {
    "should": [
    {
      "term": {
        "color": "blue"
      }
    },
    {
        "terms": {
            "toyota_type": ["a","c"]
        }
    }
   ]
  }
}
```

For the new edit case the query is as follows:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "color": {
              "value": "blue"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "type": {
                          "value": "toyota"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "type": {
                          "value": "toyota"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "terms": {
                        "toyota_type": [
                          "a",
                          "c"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am looking for 

("color is blue" AND type is not toyota) OR

("color is blue" AND type IS toyota AND toyota_type = 'a' or 'c')

Comment: Modified my answer, please have a look now